# Useage of aggregate function but without having clause

Tags: sql, select, group-by, h2, having

Im have the following two tables created:

```
create table partei(
id int not null primary key ,
name varchar(20),
vorsitzender varchar(20)
);

create table abgeordneter(
name varchar(20),
partei int references partei ,
wahlkreis varchar(20)
)
```

How can I change this Select-Statement:

```
SELECT a.Partei
FROM Abgeordneter a, Partei p
WHERE a.Partei = p.ID
GROUP BY a.Partei
HAVING COUNT(a.Name) < 5
```

Into a statement which doesn't use the having clause, but delivers exactly the same results? Is it even possible?

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what oyu need

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's not my code its a previous exam task from my professor

Comment: @letstrythisone44 If your professor is teching you this code, I would suggest you change professor. Modern JOIN syntax has been available since SQL-92. Just saying...

Comment: @letstrythisone44 . . . You can give The Impaler's advice as a message to the department/school where you are attending.  They are doing you a disservice teaching you this material.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery an eliminate the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Partei
FROM (SELECT a.Partei, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM Abgeordneter ap
      GROUP BY a.Partei
     ) a
WHERE cnt < 5;
```